# Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception: Invalid controller specified on SOME controllers

Tags: zend-framework

I'm having a bit of trouble on some of my controllers.

Some of them load fine but some of them produce the Invalid controller specified error. All are contained inside the 'controller' folder, file names and class names are named the same way for all. In my bootstrap though, the controllers that work are the ones which I have added routes to include parameters (so I tried adding a route to one of the non-working controller but it's still invalid.) I haven't found any other difference between these two groups. Any advice on where to look next?

EDIT: All controllers work on localhost.

file name, class name and example url of..

Working controller:

- FacultyController.php
- FacultyController
- .../public/index.php/Faculty/get-personal-info-profile/admin

Non-working controller:

- AccountManagementController.php
- AccountManagementController
- ../public/index.php/AccountManagement/change-password

Comment: Can you post class name, controller filename and example URL for one that works, and one that doesn't; and an example of your working route?

Comment: Since you said it works on localhost, check the case of your filenames too - Windows isn't case sensitive, Linux is, so this can catch people out sometimes.

Comment: @Tim Fountain I am using XAMPP and the server I'm uploading to is linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use camelCase Controller names by default with zend framework.

Try to Rename "AccountManagementController" to AccountmanagementController, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks! I got them working now. I don't get why the documentation states that Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard defines controllers as MixedCasedClasses ending in the word Controller though. How can I enable camel casing?